# Does visual studio have a source file projection like in sublime text or pycharm?

Tags: visual-studio

I really like the feature in pycharm and sublimetext where the source code is projected in a semi-transparent fashion on the right edge of the file being edited.  I was wondering if anyone knows what that feature is properly called, and if there are any extensions for visual studio that implement the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "minimap", and is available via an extension, called "Productivity Power Tool".

More info can be found in

https://sergeytihon.com/2012/07/17/visual-studio-minimap/